# How to use ACM certificate to authenticate with ECR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

I am performing a POC where I need to create a docker image and push to the ECR. Then spin up a ECS Fargate cluster. I am not given any ACCESS_KEY and SECRET_ACCESS_KEY but all I got is a wildcard ACM certificate in a Route53 hosted zone in a specific region.

I am able to create a load balancer and import the ACM certificate there. Also I created the image on my local box but I am not able to understand about how to push it to ECR as I don't have the credentials to authenticate (i.e., ACCESS_KEY and SECRET_ACCESS_KEY). Any pointers on this will be helpful.

Comment: Wildcard ACM certificate whose purpose in life is to just facilitate SSL doesn't really help much in your POC. I believe you will have to use cli (And thereby AWS AK and SAK) to authenticate to ECR. Please see below:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/docker-push-ecr-image.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/registry_auth.html

Comment: Thank you very much for the pointers. That was really helpful!